# Strange toString behaviour when extending Array class

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I'm trying to use the `map` function inside the `toString` overwritten in my `Array` subclass and I'm seeing a strange behaviour. It looks like that `.map` is calling the constructor of my subclass for no apparent reason and throwing a `TypeError`.

```js
class Seq extends Array {
    constructor(seq = '') {
        super();
        (seq.match(/.{2}/g) || []).forEach((mi) => this.push(mi));
    }
    toString() {
        return this.map(it=>it).join('');
    }
}
new Seq('1643').toString() //expects to see '1643' as the output but getting a TypeError
```

Recreating the array in the `toString` method fixes the problem, but I'd like to understand why.

```
toString() {
    return [...this].map(it=>it).join('');
}
```

Comment: The first step (actually the 4th after confirming  *this*, *length* and *callback*) of map is to create another of the ArrayLike class that called map which in your case is your Seq class. [Array.prototype.map](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.map)

Comment: "*`map` is calling the constructor of my subclass for no apparent reason*" - well it needs to create a new `Seq` instance

Comment: Why are you doing `.map(it=>it)` for no apparent reason? SCNR

Comment: The real thing has been reduced to the minimal that reproduces the problem.

Comment: As pointed out by @pilchard the map function will call the callbackFn for every item of the array and then it will instantiate a new Seq class. And as you see, the Seq class constructor is not prepared for that.

Comment: As you just noted, you aren't handling the [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array#parameters) expected by `Array`, it would be straighforward enough to check for a single parameter which `isSafeInteger` and handle it appropriately.